# Selecting random images from an array that’s made of 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

Hi all I’m new to the site and I’m working on a project for class using HTML CSS and JavaScript. The project is kind of like a “whack a mole game” if I can call it that. I have an array of “good” images that gives you a point if clicked and an array of “bad” images that subtracts a point if clicked. The problem and question I have is this. I want a random image to be selected from the combined arrays and if a 'good' image is selected it will add a point and if a 'bad' image is selected it will subtract a point. So far all it does is add a point because as I have read when I put an array into my if condition it returns 'true' no matter what. Here is an example of what I mean if it makes sense.

```js
let score = 1;

let problems = [
    'images/bad/angryex.jpg',
    'images/bad/badcredit.jpg',
    'images/bad/badkids.jpg',
    'images/bad/boss.jpg',
    'images/bad/carinsurance.png',
    'images/bad/carnote.jpg',
    'images/bad/carproblems.jpg',
    'images/bad/daycare.png',
    'images/bad/fakefriends.jpg',
    'images/bad/gasbill.jpg',
    'images/bad/lightbill.jpg',
    'images/bad/medicalbill.jpg',
    'images/bad/phonebill.png',
    'images/bad/rentbill.jpg',
    'images/bad/studentloan.jpg'
];

let blessings = [
    'images/good/bonus.png',
    'images/good/dayOff.png',
    'images/good/newCar.jpeg',
    'images/good/payday.jpeg',
    'images/good/promotion.jpeg',
    'images/good/shopping.jpeg',
    'images/good/spa.jpeg',
    'images/good/taxRefund.jpeg',
    'images/good/vacation.jpeg',
];

//Combine the 2 arrays into one//
let allImages = problems.concat(blessings);
console.log(allImages.length);

// Generate random image and chooses random tile//
function randomImage() {
    let randomImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allImages.length);
    let randomTileIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9); // Assuming you have 9 tiles//
    let tile = document.getElementById(randomTileIndex.toString());

    //Makes sure that only one image can cover a hat at any one time//
    while (tile.firstChild) {
        tile.firstChild.remove();
    }

    // Create a new img element
    let imgElement = document.createElement('img');
    imgElement.src = allImages[randomImageIndex];
    imgElement.style.width = '70px';
    imgElement.style.position = 'relative';
    imgElement.style.marginLeft = '40px'
    //Had to assign the element a class name here in JS to be able to style it in CSS
    imgElement.className = 'images'

    // Append the img element to the tile
    tile.appendChild(imgElement);

    //add or subtract to score//
    function scorer() {
        imgElement.onclick = function() {
            this.remove();
            if (blessings.includes(this.src)) {
                document.getElementById("score").innerText = 'Score: ' + score;
                score++
                console.log(score);
            } else if (problems.includes(this.src)) {
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = 'Score: ' + score;
                score--
                console.log(score);
            } else {
                console.log('we got it');
            }

        };
    }
    scorer()
}
```

Comment: apart from a sort of convoluted summary, there is no question in this "question"

Comment: Thanks Mister Jojo. I will try to rephrase the question and post again

Comment: Apologies Mr. Jojo. Basically I took two arrays which were 'blessings' and 'problems' and combined them into a new array which is 'allImages'. I combined them because I want a random image to show from either of the arrays. When a user clicks one of the images I want my function to do one of two things based on which image is clicked and which array its located in. So if a user clicks on one of the 'problems' images it subtracts from the score and vice versa for the 'blessings' images where it would add. Apologies if I don't make any sense or am confusing because i am confused myself lol

Comment: @user23471531 I think you explained what you want to achieve but not what specific problem you're facing or what specific question you're having. Try to explain not only what you want to get to, but also what specific part of it is getting you problems. The code you posted makes sense but you need to point what specific part of it is not behaving as you expect

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely rare that someone will come here to debug your code.
I leave you here an algorithm corresponding to your problem

```js
const images =
  { bad  : [ 'angryex.jpg', 'badcredit.jpg', 'badkids.jpg', 'boss.jpg', 'carinsurance.png', 'carnote.jpg', 'carproblems.jpg', 'daycare.png'
           , 'fakefriends.jpg', 'gasbill.jpg', 'lightbill.jpg', 'medicalbill.jpg', 'phonebill.png', 'rentbill.jpg', 'studentloan.jpg' ] 
  , good : [ 'bonus.png','dayOff.png','newCar.jpeg','payday.jpeg','promotion.jpeg','shopping.jpeg','spa.jpeg','taxRefund.jpeg','vacation.jpeg' ]
  , done : []
  }
function PickOne()
  {
  let randomInt, max  = images.bad.length + images.good.length; 

  if ( images.done.length === max) throw new Error('all images are done');
  do
    {
    randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    } 
  while (images.done.includes(randomInt))

  images.done.push( randomInt );

  let fileUrl = 'images/' 
              + ((randomInt < images.bad.length) 
                ? ('bad/'  + images.bad[randomInt])
                : ('good/' + images.good[randomInt - images.bad.length] ))

  return ({ point : (randomInt < images.bad.length ? -1 : +1), fileUrl })
  }

console.log( '1', JSON.stringify( PickOne() )); 
console.log( '2', JSON.stringify( PickOne() ));
console.log( '3', JSON.stringify( PickOne() ));
console.log( '4', JSON.stringify( PickOne() ));
```